# Setup Brand New OpenVPN to allow LAN Connection

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn

So i'm new to openVPN, after setting it up, and connecting between client - server , i need both to allow LAN connection

So my setup is as follow (as for now)
Client is set on the 192.168.1.X ip range
Server is set on the same range (OpenVPN is installed on 192.168.1.2)
Gateway on server "network" is 192.168.1.254

i need the client to connect to server and , for example, access a smb share on it

This is both the Server and Client ovpn file

SERVER OVPN

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca "C:\\OpenVPN\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\OpenVPN\\server.crt"
key "C:\\OpenVPN\\server.key" # This file should be kept secret
dh "C:\\OpenVPN\\dh2048.pem"
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

CLIENT OVPN

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca "C:\\OpenVPN\\VPN1-ca.crt"
cert "C:\\OpenVPN\\VPN1.crt"
key "C:\\OpenVPN\\VPN1.key"
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 3
```

I know it sucks just "asking" for it, but tried changing to dev tap, routing, etc and i just can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You just set up a routing OpenVPN. Thus:

1. your LAN should have route to VPN network and that route is through server running OpenVPN
2. your VPN client should have route to LAN and that route is via its VPN "gateway"
3. your firewalls should permit all those packets

To achieve first target, you need proper routing on each system in the LAN. If your VPN server is already a default gateway for them, you're done. If it isn't, either set up a  route on each LAN system (try "route -p add 10.8.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.2" for Windows systems in LAN) or set up such route to 10.8.0.0/24 on the system which is default gateway for the LAN.

To achieve second target, you have to push route to your client or have that route configured in each client config. The first way is more flexible and clean, thus it is preferred. Add into server config:

```
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
```

(You haven't provided an exact netmask, I assume you have /24 network.)

OpenVPN route command in this form will set up route on a client via its "inside OpenVPN" address.

Your OpenVPN server is set up in routing mode, so it is "router" itself. It can be thought as a router with N+1 interfaces, where N is number of currently connected clients and one is server. You set it up in "net30" mode, read manual for details, in short it means a server and each client is assigned a /30 mini-network (each has two usable addresses). Server is assigned .0/30, first client is assigned .4/30 and so on. Server has address .1, so "router interface" which is facing server has an address .2 and this is nexthop to VPN network on the server; first client will have address .6, its "router interface" will be .5 and that is client's next hop into VPN network and what is behind is (your LAN). These nexthop addresses are part of OpenVPN process(es) and you won't be able to ping them, don't even try. Client with 10.8.0.6 address will have routes: 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.5 and 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.8.0.5. This last route is what you added with the "push route" command.

It could happen that your LAN is 192.168.1.0/24 and your remote client's LAN is 192.168.1.0/24 and all it behind NAT of course. If client already had a route to 192.168.1.0/24, it's LAN access via that route will be screwed. But OpenVPN is not so dumb; if your client accesses OpenVPN server with the help of that route, OpenVPN will create specific route for just server access and then overtake the rest. For example, if remote client has 192.168.1.5/24 in it's LAN and default gateway 192.168.1.1 (that has nothing to do with your 192.168.1.5 and 192.168.1.1 in your LAN where server lives), it should have a LAN route 192.168.1.0/24 via physical interface. Upon connection that route will be replaced to with 192.168.1.1/32 (to a single host) via physical interface and 192.168.1.0/24 via VPN nexthop (which is 10.8.0.5 for the first client). So it will be able to connect to all hosts in your LAN behind VPN server, except for .1 (its local router) and .5 (itself), but it wouldn't be able to connect to all other local systems with 192.168.1.x addresses (because VPN route to 192.168.1.0/24 had overtaken that and packets will go to VPN and not to LAN). This is why I strongly suggest NOT to use 192.168.0.x and 192.168.1.x in the office, just to reduce risk of such collisions.

Last item, firewall. Many people just forget about this, so I only added it here as a reminder. I am not an expert in Windows firewall, so I'll let someone else to help you with that :)

A final note. Please, read complete OpenVPN manual page. It is a description what OpenVPN could do; it is capable of many things, much more than you will use, but it is great to know the full capability, in case you need it. Also you will have an opportunity to refine and better understand my explanation of its internals, including "official" description of what "route" and "push" really do. For example, you can include external files (certificates and keys) inside the config, this is very convenient to set it up on clients with only single "bundle" file.